# Angular JS - Ionic - Fullscreen Image script

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, fullscreen

```js
angular.module('mattymode.controllers', ['ionic'])


.controller('FB_Ctrl', function($scope,$http) {

function makeHttpRequest() {

try {return new XMLHttpRequest();}
catch (error) {}

try {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
catch (error) {}

try {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
catch (error) {}

throw new Error ("HTTP Request Could not be completed.");
}


var appID = "appID";
var appSecret = "appSecret";

var accessTokenRq = makeHttpRequest();
var httpString = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='+appID+'&client_secret='+appSecret;

accessTokenRq.open("GET",httpString,true);
accessTokenRq.send(null);

var access_token;

accessTokenRq.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if (accessTokenRq.readyState == 4) {

    access_token = accessTokenRq.responseText;
    //alert("It works!");

    var request = makeHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET",'https://graph.facebook.com/535142566615553/posts?'+access_token+'&fields=id,message,picture,link,name,description,type,icon,likes,comments,created_time,from,object_id&limit=10)',true);
    request.send(null);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if (request.readyState == 4) {

        var response = request.responseText;
        console.log(response);

        var fbData = angular.fromJson(response);

        var data = fbData.data;

        var messageArray = [];
        var pictureArray = [];
        var likeArray = [];
        var dateArray = [];
        var linkArray = [];
        var typeArray = [];
        var commentArray = [];

        var objects = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          
          var entry = data[i];

          // Message
          if (entry.message) {
             var message = entry.message;
             messageArray.push(message);
          }
          else {messageArray.push(" ");}

          // Picture
          if(angular.equals(entry.type,"photo")) {
            var pic = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+entry.object_id+"/picture?type=normal";
            pictureArray.push(pic);
          }
          else if (angular.equals(entry.type,"link")) {
            pictureArray.push(entry.picture);
          }
          else {pictureArray.push("empty");}
          //console.log(pic);
            
          // Likes
          if (entry.likes) {
            var likeData = entry.likes;
            likeArray.push(likeData.data.length+" Likes");
          }
          else {likeArray.push(" Likes");}

            
          // Date 
          var created = entry.created_time;
          var rawDate = created.split("T");
          var date = rawDate[0];

          var rawTime = rawDate[1];
          var time = rawTime.split(":");
          var betaTime = time[0]+":"+time[1];
          var finalTime = addOneHour(betaTime);
          dateArray.push(date+" - "+finalTime);

            function addOneHour(time) {
              var seperatedTime = time.split(":");
              var hourTime = seperatedTime[0];
              var returningTime = "";
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("00") > -1) {returningTime = "01";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("01") > -1) {returningTime = "02";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("02") > -1) {returningTime = "03";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("03") > -1) {returningTime = "04";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("04") > -1) {returningTime = "05";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("05") > -1) {returningTime = "06";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("06") > -1) {returningTime = "07";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("07") > -1) {returningTime = "08";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("08") > -1) {returningTime = "09";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("09") > -1) {returningTime = "10";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("10") > -1) {returningTime = "11";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("11") > -1) {returningTime = "12";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("12") > -1) {returningTime = "13";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("13") > -1) {returningTime = "14";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("14") > -1) {returningTime = "15";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("15") > -1) {returningTime = "16";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("16") > -1) {returningTime = "17";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("17") > -1) {returningTime = "18";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("18") > -1) {returningTime = "19";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("19") > -1) {returningTime = "20";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("20") > -1) {returningTime = "21";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("21") > -1) {returningTime = "22";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("22") > -1) {returningTime = "23";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("23") > -1) {returningTime = "00";}

                console.log(returningTime+":"+seperatedTime[1]);

              return returningTime+":"+seperatedTime[1];  

              }

          // Link
          if (entry.link) {linkArray.push("empty");}
          else {linkArray.push("empty");}

          // Comments 
          if (entry.comments) {
            var commentData = entry.comments;
            commentArray.push(commentData.data.length+" Comments");

          }
          else {
            commentArray.push("0 Comments");
          }


          typeArray.push(entry.type);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
          
          // Only Text 
          if ( (angular.equals(linkArray[i],"empty")) && (angular.equals(pictureArray[i],"empty")) ) {
            objects.push('<div class="list card"><div class="item thumbnail-left"> <h2>Matty Mode</h2><p>'+dateArray[i]+'</p></div><div class="item item-body"><p>'+messageArray[i]+'</p><p><span class="subdued">'+likeArray[i]+'</span>  <span class="subdued">'+commentArray[i]+'</span></p></div> <a class="button-block button">Bekijk</a> </div>');
          
          }

          // No Link, picture availiable
          else if ( (angular.equals(linkArray[i],"empty")) && (angular.equals(pictureArray[i],"empty")) == false ) {
            objects.push('<div class="list card"><div class="item thumbnail-left"> <h2>Matty Mode</h2><p>'+dateArray[i]+'</p></div><div class="item item-body"><img src="'+pictureArray[i]+'" width=100%></img> <p>'+messageArray[i]+'</p><p><span class="subdued">'+likeArray[i]+'</span>  <span class="subdued">'+commentArray[i]+'</span></p></div> <a class="button-block button">Bekijk</a> </div>');

          }

          // The rest 
          else {
            objects.push('<div class="list card"><div class="item thumbnail-left"> <h2>Matty Mode</h2><p>'+dateArray[i]+'</p></div><div class="item item-body"><a href='+linkArray[i]+' ><img src="'+pictureArray[i]+'" width=100%></img></a> <p>'+messageArray[i]+'</p><p><span class="subdued">'+likeArray[i]+'</span>  <span class="subdued">'+commentArray[i]+'</span></p></div> <a class="button-block button">Bekijk</a> </div>');

          }

        }

        $scope.entries = objects;
        $scope.pictures = pictureArray;
      }
    }
  }

}


})

.controller('IMG_Ctrl', ['$scope', '$ionicModal', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
    
   $scope.aImages = [{
       'src' : $scope.pictures[0], 
       'msg' : ''
     }, {
        'src' : $scope.pictures[1], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, { 
        'src' : $scope.pictures[2], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, { 
        'src' : $scope.pictures[3], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, { 
        'src' : $scope.pictures[4], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, {
        'src' : $scope.pictures[5], 
       'msg' : ''
     }, {
        'src' : $scope.pictures[6], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, { 
        'src' : $scope.pictures[7], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, { 
        'src' : $scope.pictures[8], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, { 
        'src' : $scope.pictures[9], 
        'msg' : ''
    }];
    
    //console.log($scope.pictures);
  
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('image-modal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
    });

    $scope.openModal = function() {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(0);
      $scope.modal.show();
    };

    $scope.closeModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.hide();
    };

    // Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      $scope.modal.remove();
    });
    // Execute action on hide modal
    $scope.$on('modal.hide', function() {
      // Execute action
    });
    // Execute action on remove modal
    $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
      // Execute action
    });
    $scope.$on('modal.shown', function() {
      console.log('Modal is shown!');
    });

    // Call this functions if you need to manually control the slides
    $scope.next = function() {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    };
  
    $scope.previous = function() {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.previous();
    };
  
   $scope.goToSlide = function(index) {
      $scope.modal.show();
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index);
    };
  
    // Called each time the slide changes
    $scope.slideChanged = function(index) {
      $scope.slideIndex = index;
    };
  }
])

.controller('FAQ_Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [];

  $scope.groups = [
  { name: 'Hoe werkt deze app?', id: 1, items: ['Met deze app kunt u onze hipste en meeste betaalbare mode bekijken op uw mobiel of tablet. Elke week zullen er meerdere outfits beschikbaar zijn, daar wij iedere weekeen nieuwe collecite in de winkel hebben, waarvan de meeste slechts voor een korte periode beschikbaar zijn.']},
  { name: 'Reserveren', id: 2, items: ['Ja, dat kan, u kunt ons bellen of whatsappen op nummer 06-*******, wat u het fijnst vindt, let wel, wij hangen de bestelling voor maximaal 3 dagen apart, daarna gaat het terug bij de collectie.']},
  { name: 'Retourneren', id: 3, items: ['U kunt artiekelen binnen 1 week ruilen, op vertoon van de bijbehorende kassabon, mits deze niet gedragen en/of gewassen zijn, en enkel als de kaartjes nog aan de kleding vastzitten. LET WEL: Wij geven geen geld terug, u ontvangt van ons een tegoedbon, voor het aankoopsbedrag.']},
  { name: 'We geven geen garantie', id: 4, items: ['Strasssteentjes', 'Kwastjes', 'Kettingen', 'Emblemen', 'Loslatende naalden of stikkels', 'Verkeerde wasvoorschriften/gebruik']},
  ];
  
  /*
   * if given group is the selected group, deselect it
   * else, select the given group
   */
  $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
    if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
      $scope.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
      $scope.shownGroup = group;
    }
  };
  $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
    return $scope.shownGroup === group;
  };
  
});
```

```css
/* Fullscreen image */
.transparent {
  background: transparent !important;
}
.image-modal {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}
.fullscreen-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 55px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* Fix modal backdrop for smaller devices */
@media (max-width: 679px) {
  .active .modal-backdrop-bg {
    opacity: .5;
  }
  .modal-backdrop-bg {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* Accordion lists */
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}

/*
 * http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#usage_animations
 */
.list .item.item-accordion {
  line-height: 38px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.09s all linear;
}
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide {
  line-height: 0px;
}
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-add,
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-remove {
  display: block !important;
}

.item.wrap, .item-content.wrap {
white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="mattymode">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a problem, been at this for a long time and just can't get it to work, guy's help me out here.

I have an `AngularJS, HTML webapp`, the app fetches the posts from an `FB page` that is in `JSON`, and displays the `images` in cards with pictures and text, that the user can scroll down, currently 10 cards are displayed, everything is working just fine, except one thing, when the user clicks the `image`, it alway's opens the first image from there the user can scroll.

What i need is that when the user clicks, it's the same number, as the card the user clicks at that moment. Please help! :)

As you can see the `images` are loaded by this piece of `script`:

```
    $scope.aImages = [{
    'src' : $scope.pictures[0], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, {
    'src' : $scope.pictures[1], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, { 
    'src' : $scope.pictures[2], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, { 
    'src' : $scope.pictures[3], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, { 
    'src' : $scope.pictures[4], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, {
    'src' : $scope.pictures[5], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, {
    'src' : $scope.pictures[6], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, { 
    'src' : $scope.pictures[7], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, { 
    'src' : $scope.pictures[8], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, { 
    'src' : $scope.pictures[9], 
    'msg' : ''
    }];
```

The `fullscreen modal` that opens, is opened by this piece of `script`:

```
    $scope.openModal = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(0);
    $scope.modal.show();
    };
```

Comment: You need to provide code for your view and controller.

Comment: The code is now included!

Comment: Please narrow down the problem. Create a working demo example in http://play.ionic.io for better understanding of your problem. This question just has too much code and can't really tell what is going on.

Comment: @ShadiShaaban

The code is now included!

Comment: @thepio

Can't get it to work through ionic.play, can send you the preview through ionic.io, leave your e-mail adress, i'll send you a link.